# Expecto FsCheck getting stack overflow exception when generating string

Tags: f#, fscheck, property-based-testing, expecto

I'm trying to learn how to use FsCheck properly, and integrating it with Expecto at the moment. I can get property tests to run if I'm using the default FsCheck config, but when I try to use my own Generator, it causes a stack overflow exception.

Here is my generator

```
type NameGen() =
    static member Name() =
        Arb.generate<string * string>
        |> Gen.where (fun (firstName, lastName) ->
            firstName.Length > 0 && lastName.Length > 0
        )
        |> Gen.map (fun (first, last) -> sprintf "%s %s" first last)
        |> Arb.fromGen
        |> Arb.convert string id
```

And I'm trying to use it like this:

```
let config = { FsCheckConfig.defaultConfig with arbitrary = [typeof<NameGen>] }

let propertyTests input =
    let output = toInitials input
    output.EndsWith(".")

testPropertyWithConfig config "Must end with period" propertyTests
```

The exception is thrown before it even gets into the `Gen.where` function

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to use FsCheck's generator of strings to redefine how its generator of strings work, but when you do that, it'll recursively call itself until it runs out of stack space. It's a known issue: https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/issues/109

Does this alternative work?

```
type NameGen =
    static member Name () =
        Arb.Default.NonEmptyString().Generator
        |> Gen.map (fun (NonEmptyString s) -> s)
        |> Gen.two
        |> Gen.map (fun (first, last) -> sprintf "%s %s" first last)
        |> Arb.fromGen
```

Answer (score 3):

You are defining a new generator for the type string, but within that you're using the generator for `string * string`, which uses the generator for `string`. FsCheck unfortunately seems to store generators in global mutable state (perhaps with good reason?) and I think this means that the generator keeps calling itself until stack overflow.

You could solve this by defining the generator for a custom wrapper type instead of a plain string (shown below).

The next problem you'll hit will be null reference exceptions. The initial generated string could be `null` and you try to access the `.Length` property. This can be resolved using the `String.length` function instead, which returns `0` for `null`.

With these changes your generator looks like this:

```
type Name = Name of string

type NameGen() =
    static member Name() =
        Arb.generate<string * string>
        |> Gen.where (fun (firstName, lastName) ->
            String.length firstName > 0 && String.length lastName > 0
        )
        |> Gen.map (fun (first, last) -> sprintf "%s %s" first last)
        |> Arb.fromGen
        |> Arb.convert Name (fun (Name n) -> n)
```

And your property needs a slight modification:

```
let propertyTests (Name input) =
    let output = toInitials input
    output.EndsWith(".")
```